# Complexity of $FP^{NP[O(n)]}$ with advice string?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, oracles, advice-and-nonuniformity

$FP^{NP[O(n)]}$ is the functional complexity class with $O(n)$ queries to an $NP$ oracle.

Are there any interesting classes $\mathcal C$ such that
$$FP^{NP[O(n)]}\subseteq\mathcal C/\log$$
besides $FP^{NP[O(n)]}$ itself? 
In particular, can we show that $FP^{NP[O(n)]}\subseteq FP^{NP[f(n)]}/\log$ for some $f(n) = o(n)$?

Comment: They belong to $\mathrm{FP^{NP}\!\!/log}$, by definition. What else do you expect to hear?

Comment: Thanks. my query was regarding the number of Oracle calls required for the new problem (assuming the advise string). I am not conversant in this notation (haven't seen one above), I am assuming this is equivalent to $FP^{NP[log]}$ oracle calls given the advise string.

Comment: No. “/log” means “with logarithmic advice”. There is no restriction on the number of oracle calls, as there wasn’t one in $\mathrm{FP^{NP}}$ to begin with. I am more and more at loss to understand what is it that you are trying to ask.

Comment: Ok. My mistake. I thought the notation $FP^{NP}$ implicitly had the linear number of calls restriction (thus I mentioned in the query above). So, to clarify I am looking how a log sized advise string would affect the problem's calls where original problem had a linear number of $NP$ query restrictions.

Comment: I still have no idea what you are asking. Clearly, if you take an oracle machine making $x$ oracle calls, and supply it with an advice, it will still make the exact same number of calls.

Comment: Umm I have my doubts, I think depending on the advise the number of calls can be reduced to solve the same problems.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek He is asking whether we can reduce the number of oracle calls if we have log size advice bits

Comment: Is he? Well then, that's not what is written in the question at all.

Comment: as pointed out i was asking the same. I tried to convey it in the comments too but couldn't get it across.